# How can k-means be reduced to Integer Programming

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, integer-programming, cluster

The k-means algorithm reduces to computing the objective function:

$
\underset{\textbf{S}}{\operatorname{argmax}}  \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{\textbf{x}_j\in\textbf{S}_i} \lVert \textbf{x}_j - \mathbf{\mu}_i \rVert
$

for some observations $\textbf{x}_1,\ldots\textbf{x}_n$ to be partitioned into sets $\textbf{S}_i$.

How can this problem be reduced to an Integer Programming problem, which like k-means, is NP-hard.

Comment: k-means would be hard only if integer programming reduced to k-means, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can reduce this problem to an Integer Problem, because the centers are still continuous variables. There are ways to write equivalent Mixed-Integer Problems (i.e., both integer and continuous variables) but I struggle to formulate as a Linear one because of the Euclidean norm.

First you create a boolean variable $w_{ij}$ for assignment. $w_{ij} = 1$ means observation j belongs to cluster i (and zero means it does not belong). The following constraint ensures that one sample can only belong to one group:
$$
\sum_i{w_{ij} = 1},  \forall i \in 1..k
$$

You also create non-negative continuous variables $d_{ij} \geq 0$ for distances between every observation j to every center, but use the [Big M method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method) to turn this distance zero if the observation does not belong to the cluster:
$$
d_{ij} \geq ||x_j - \mu_i|| - M(1 - w_{ij})
$$

To select a value of M you can find the distance between the two points that are furthest from each other, or any other bigger value. If M is big enough and j doesn't belong to i, we have $d_{ij} \geq L$ where L is negative, so the constraint is trivially satisfied - which means $d_{ij}$ can assume any value greater or equal to zero. If j does belong to i, then the minimum value for $d_{ij}$ is the euclidean distance between observation and cluster center.

(Note: you could use a multiplicative factor instead of Big M, like this: $
d_{ij} = ||x_j - \mu_i||w_{ij}$ - this is matematically accurate but generally doesn't work well in practice because it adds non-linearity. But since this norm is already non-linear, who knows?)

Now, if you minimize the distances (I saw in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Description) that the correct formulation tries to minimize the sum of distances), optimization will try to reduce every single value of $d_{ij}$, so they will clamp to the correct distances if j belongs to i, and to zero if j doesn not belong to i:

$$
\min{\sum_{ij}{d_{ij}}}
$$

I hope that helps.